# What can be the cause of an hang on read with Cosmos DB in call to hasNex()?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

```
CosmosContainer fs = ...;
SqlQuerySpec sql = new SqlQuerySpec( ... );
CosmosPagedIterable<EntryPOJO> items = fs.queryItems( sql, null, EntryPOJO.class );
Iterator<EntryPOJO> it = items.iterator();
if( it.hasNext() ) {
    EntryPOJO entry = it.next();
}
```

This query should return 0 or 1 items. This code work without problems with the emulator but hang in productive system. What can be the cause?

The hanging stacktrace is:

```
"ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=52.86ms elapsed=519.67s tid=0x00007fecfd4e6a40 nid=0x61d waiting on condition  [0x00007fecfccfe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@17.0.4/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000080664c98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@17.0.4/UnknownSource)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(java.base@17.0.4/Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.compensatedBlock(java.base@17.0.4/Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@17.0.4/Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@17.0.4/Unknown Source)
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingIterable$SubscriberIterator.hasNext(BlockingIterable.java:179)
```